# Как применить файл стилей .css в главном окне программы?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt

пробую в главном окне так:

```
    def __init__(self):
...
        self.setStyleSheet("Light.css")
```

в файле Light.css:

```
QFrame#frame {
    border: 1px solid #666666;
}

QPushButton {
    background-color: #E5E5E5;
    border: 1px solid #666666;
}

QPushButton:hover {
    background-color: #666666;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

Comment: Так верно, только пути надо правильные указать

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def __init__(self):
    ...

    f = open("mystylesheet.qss")#QSS not CSS for pyqt5
    stylesheet = f.read()
    self.setStyleSheet(stylesheet)
    f.close()

    ...
```